# How to use vue-resource whit jsonp?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm trying to get data from this url,

http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_recursos_turisticos/albergues_de_euskadi/opendata/alojamientos.json

which returns a jsonp, but I can not get them with vue-resource (with pure javascript, JQuery, and some other libary like fetch-jsonp, I get them).

Could someone please post an example?

this is my code

```
new Vue({
    el: '.App',
    mounted: function () {
        this.cojerDatos()
    },



    data: {
        losDatos: {}
    },
    methods: {

        cojerDatos() {
            const url = "http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_recursos_turisticos/albergues_de_euskadi/opendata/alojamientos.json";

            this.$http.jsonp(url,{params: {jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback'}})
            .then(response => console.log(response.json()))


       },

    }
})
```

[image]

[image]

I note, moreover, that the url adds the parameters of a call to the random callback.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide snippets of code you've already tried, and how they've failed?

Comment: new Vue({
    el: '.App',
    mounted: function () {
        this.cojerDatos()
    },



    data: {
        losDatos: {}
    },
    methods: {

        cojerDatos() {
            const url = "http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_recursos_turisticos/albergues_de_euskadi/opendata/alojamientos.json?format=json¬callback=jsonCallback";

            this.$http.jsonp(url,{params: {jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback'}})
            .then(response => console.log(response.json()))


       },

    }
})

Comment: What I see is that the script that generates vue-resource does not add the parameters? jsonCalback = jsonCallback, but it generates a random callback function.

Comment: Can you add those into your original post, so others can help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I your question. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!